# How do you test when a command block does not sense a block?

Tags: minecraft-java-edition, minecraft-commands

I need an answer for testing when a player is in the air. I tried
`execute at @a[tag=tag] if block ~ ~-1 ~ air run tag @a[tag=tag] add inair` but I need to remove the tag, too. I'm thinking, `execute at @a[tag=tag,tag=inair] if block ~ ~-1 ~ !air run tag @a[tag=tag,tag=inair] add inair` but an exclamation mark doesn't work there.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

`unless block ~ ~-1 ~ air`

Syntax for block checking is at [Minecraft Wiki](https://minecraft.wiki/w/Commands/execute#(if%7Cunless)_block)

Comment: Thank you, this is really helpful. I had forgotten about the "unless" command usage.